# store docker images in jFrog artifactory - local setup

Tags: docker, artifactory

Running windows 10 and trying to setup jFrog artifactory to store docker images (locally). I've installed jFrog and am trying to create new docker repository however that option is grayed out
[image]

Based on this doc I need a free license but no license is sent when I sign up on the website.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-UsingDockerCompose-1MinuteSetup.1

How can I configure jFrog artifactory to store docker images? What setup options should I follow?

Comment: Please contact sales@jfrog.com, they would be very happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Artifactory instance is OSS version(you can see it in the footer left corner).
The OSS version does not include Docker repositories.
You will have to get a license for the Pro edition